# Save the selected controls in a list and then compare

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to save some selected controls in a list and then compare, i can only select two so it's okay.

Each of the controls have a boolean property Selected, and i need the : `Selected == True`.

How do i create a method that returns the Selected controls?

Something like:

```
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                if (  this.Selected == true )

                   {
                       // how to add to a list
                   }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LINQ` you can do it in one line, this will put all the selected controls into a list and return:

```
return Controls.Where(c => c.Selected).ToList();
```

If you want to use foreach just create a list to store controls and populate your list with selected controls:

```
var selectedControls = new List<Control>();
foreach(var c in Controls)
{
    if(c.Selected) selectedControls.Add(c);
}

return selectedControls;
```

Comment: Thank you, how do i insert the following code in a proper method, can you just show me the code inside the foreach loop

Comment: you can get rid of foreach

Comment: just let me keep the foreach for my understanding, i can see it's easier like you do